# My initialized variable is displayed empty

Tags: c++

My string `d` is displayed empty (not even a space) on my console, this is getting me confused since I initialized it to "NULL" and I am trying to assign a new value  to it which isn't a empty value.

```
int main(){

    string user_String[99];
    int user_Input = 0;

    cout << "Please insert up to one hundred Strings: ";
    cin >> user_Input;


    //Check for range
    bool check = false;
    while( check == false){
        if (user_Input < 1 || user_Input >100){
            cout << "Please insert up to one hundred Strings: ";
            cin >> user_Input;}
        else{
            check = true;
            break;}
    }   

    //User input
    cout <<"Please enter string"<< endl;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < user_Input; counter++){
        int counter2 = counter + 1;
        cout << "Enter String " << counter2 << ": ";
        cin >> user_String[counter];
    }

    //Loopig for most letters
    string c = "NULL"; 
    for(int counter = 0; counter < user_Input; counter++){
        //Making Sure Coun doesn't go out of range
        int coun = 0;
        if (counter < user_Input){
            coun = counter +1;}
        else{
            coun = counter; 
        }

        string a = user_String[counter];
        string b = user_String[coun];       

        if (a.length() < b.length() && c == "NULL"){
            c = b;
        }

        if(a.length() < b.length() && c!="NULL" && c.length() < b.length()){
            c = b;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }

    }
    cout << "The string "<< c <<" have the most letters." << endl;

    //Looping for least letters
    string d = "NULL"; 
    for(int counter = 0; counter < user_Input; counter++){
        //Making Sure Coun doesn't go out of range
        int coun = 0;
        if (counter < user_Input){
            coun = counter +1;}
        else{
            coun = counter; 
        }

        string a = user_String[counter];
        string b = user_String[coun];

        if (a.length() > b.length() && d == "NULL"){
            d = b;
        }

        if(a.length() > b.length() && d!="NULL" && d.length() > b.length()){
            d = b;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    cout << "The string " << d <<" have the least letters." << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would get very confused if a program told me to enter strings and expected an integer.

Comment: How can you be sure the new value you assigned it isn't empty?  I would recommend stepping through with a debugger to see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allow the user to enter up to 100 strings, but your array can only hold up to 99 strings.  If they actually enter 100 strings, the last string will corrupt memory, assume your code does not crash altogether.

Also, your letters loops have some faulty logic in them. `if (counter < user_Input)` will always be true, so `coun` will always be `counter+1` and thus exceed the bounds of the array when `counter` reaches the end of the array.  Also, your loops are unnecessarily complex for what they are trying to do.

Try this instead:

```
int main()
{
    string user_String[100];
    int user_Input;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of Strings (1-100): ";
        if (cin >> user_Input)
        {
            if ((user_Input >= 1) && (user_Input <= 100))
                break;
        }
        else
            cin.clear();
    }
    while (true);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < user_Input; ++counter)
    {
        cout << "Enter String " << counter + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> user_String[counter];
    }

    string b = user_String[0]; 
    for(int counter = 1; counter < user_Input; ++counter)
    {
        string a = user_String[counter];
        if (a.length() > b.length())
            b = a;
    }

    cout << "The string " << b << " has the most letters." << endl;

    b = user_String[0]; 
    for(int counter = 1; counter < user_Input; ++counter)
    {
        string a = user_String[counter];
        if (a.length() < b.length())
            b = a;
    }

    cout << "The string " << b <<" has the least letters." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, you can get rid of the array altogether and merge the loops together:

```
int main()
{
    string user_String;
    int user_Input;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter the number of Strings: ";
        if (cin >> user_Input)
        {
            if (user_Input >= 1)
                break;
        }
        else
            cin.clear();
    }
    while (true);

    string fewestLetters, mostLetters;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= user_Input; ++counter)
    {
        cout << "Enter String " << counter << ": ";
        cin >> user_String;

        if (counter == 1)
        {
            mostLetters = user_String;
            fewestLetters = user_String;
        }
        else
        {
            if (user_String.length() > mostLetters.length())
                mostLetters = user_String;

            if (user_String.length() < fewestLetters.length())
                fewestLetters = user_String;
        }
    }

    cout << "The string " << mostLetters << " has the most letters." << endl;
    cout << "The string " << fewestLetters << " has the least letters." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the second example, wouldn't fewestLetters always be length 0 and thus never assigned anything?  I'd add a check !empty() to make sure the first string gets assigned to it to start the ball rolling.

Comment: If you enter `a` as the number of strings, this goes into an infinite loop.  Try `while(!( std::cin >> user_Input )) {std::cin.clear(); std::cout << "Please enter the number of Strings (1-100):";}`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks. I have incorporated a check for `>>` failure.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: and `if (!cin >> user_String[counter]) throw std::runtime_error("bad input");`?

Comment: @MooingDuck: And if the user actually types in a blank string?  Should it be counted or ignored? That is for Daniel to decide based on his actual requirements. His original code allowed blank strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `std::cin >> user_String[counter]` will _never ever ever_ read in a blank string (though it may remain blank if the stream is in a failstate).  If that's your concern, then your code is wrong.  Luckily, his code doesn't allow empty strings, and mine duplicates his functionality for correct input.  Also, your code has an infinite loop if it reaches the end of the stream at that point.  (Try `if (!std::getline(cin, user_String[counter])) throw std::runtime_error("bad input");` if you want empty lines to be allowed)